# validate empty value on textbox ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have problem about validating empty textbox

My textbox

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Width="272px" AutoCompleteType="Disabled">
```

My label

```
<asp:Label ID="warning" runat="server" Text="you forgot about this" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
```

my validation

```
if (TextBox1.Text == "")
            {
                warning.Visible = true;
            }
```

it can validate the empty textbox but it can't validate space input

can anybody help me please?

Comment: why you didn't use ASP.NET validators control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because a space isn't `""`, so they're not equal.

You can use `.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text))
```

This has the added benefit of also checking for `null` (though in this particular case I don't think `.Text` would ever be `null`) as well as any other purely whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

try to use RequiredFieldValidator it validates both client side and server side and also ignore whitespaces during validation.
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator(v=vs.110).aspx